# WebSocket endpoint and CDI injection: No active contexts for scope RequestScoped

Tags: java, cdi, weld, java-websocket

I want to inject a `@RequestScoped` CDI bean in my Java EE 7 WebSocket endpoint.

However I am getting error `WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`.

What am I doing wrong and why it is not possible?

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Storage {

}
```

Which I `@Inject` in the endpoint like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/serverpush")
public class ContratoEndpoint {

    @Inject
    private Storage storage;

}
```

And I am getting the following stack trace:

```
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:689)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.getIfExists(ContextualInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @John mentioned, `RequestContext` is not active in WebSocket methods. Instead of using Deltaspike (which is a good option), you can also write your own Interceptor to activate/deactivate weld `RequestContext`.

As you are using Wildfly, you can use weld as a provided dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you can define an `InterceptorBinding` `@RequestContextOperation` :

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;

@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface RequestContextOperation
{

}
```

And the corresponding `RequestContextInterceptor` where we activate/deactivate the `RequestContext`:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

import org.jboss.weld.context.RequestContext;
import org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.Unbound;

@Interceptor
@RequestContextOperation
public class RequestContextInterceptor {

    /** The RequestContext */
    @Inject
    @Unbound
    private RequestContext m_requestContext;

    /**
     * 
     * @param p_invocationContext
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object activateRequestContext(final InvocationContext p_invocationContext) throws Exception {
        try {
            m_requestContext.activate();
            return p_invocationContext.proceed();
        } finally {
            m_requestContext.invalidate();
            m_requestContext.deactivate();
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use the `@RequestContextOperation` annotation on your class or on a specific method :

```
@ServerEndpoint("/serverpush")
public class ContratoEndpoint {

    @Inject
    private Storage storage;

    @OnMessage
    @RequestContextOperation
    public String handleMessage(String message){

        // Here the @RequestScoped bean is valid thanks to the @RequestContextOperation InterceptorBinding
        storage.yourMethod();
        ....
    }

}
```

Comment: @BonanzaOne @Rouliboy While this is good approach, I would first try one that is **already present in Weld**. If you set a dependency on Weld API, that you can annotate your methods/classes with pre-defined interceptor binding `@ActivateRequestContext` which does exactly what you seek. You can read more about it in [Weld Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_request_context). While this is originally designed for SE environment, it should work in EE all the same.

Comment: @Siliarus : I didn't know this, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets do not initialize a request scope context for their method invocations.  You can use [deltaspike context control](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/container-control.html#ContextControlUsage) to manually start a request context for the method invocation.

Comment: I am using WildFly, any solution without external dependencies?

Comment: since its apache licensed, using the source code shouldn't be an issue https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/cdictrl/impl-weld/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/cdise/weld/WeldContextControl.java#L158  you may not need all these complexities

Comment: @BonanzaOne : I updated my answer using Weld which is part of WildFly server.

Answer (score 0):

Although Request Scope is not active in WebSockets (including Atmosphere) you can manually activate it using the approach proposed in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42442415).

However, since CDI 2.0, you can use the `@ActivateRequestContext` annotation (from `javax.enterprise.context.control.ActivateRequestContext`) interceptor to do just that.

Either annotate the class or the method where you want to have Request Scope and this will activate it at the beginning of method execution and deactivate it when it finishes,